# Extends a class that extends the Hadoop's Mapper

Tags: java, hadoop

This is an example of a Map class [1] from the Hadoop that extends the Mapper class. [3] is the Hadoop's Mapper class.

I want to create my `MyExampleMapper` that extends the `ExampleMapper` that also extends the hadoop's `Mapper` [2]. I do this because I just want to set a property in the `ExampleMapper` so that, when I create the `MyExampleMapper` or other examples, I don't have to set the property myself because I have extended the `ExampleMapper`. Is it possible to do this?

[1] Example mapper

```
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;

public class ExampleMapper 
     extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable>{

   private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
   private Text word = new Text();

   public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
     StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
     while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
       word.set(itr.nextToken());
       context.write(word, one);
     }
   }
 }
```

[2] What I want

```
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;

public class MyExampleMapper 
     extends ExampleMapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable>{

   private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
   private Text word = new Text();

   public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
     StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());

     String result = System.getProperty("job.examplemapper")

     if (result.equals("true")) {
       while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
         word.set(itr.nextToken());
         context.write(word, one);
       }
     }
   }
 }


public class ExampleMapper<KEYIN, VALUEIN, KEYOUT, VALUEOUT> 
     extends Mapper{

   System.setProperty("job.examplemapper", "true");
 }
```

[3] This is the Hadoop's Mapper class

```
public class Mapper<KEYIN, VALUEIN, KEYOUT, VALUEOUT> {
    public Mapper() {
    }

    protected void setup(Mapper.Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    }

    protected void map(KEYIN key, VALUEIN value, Mapper.Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        context.write(key, value);
    }

    protected void cleanup(Mapper.Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    }

    public void run(Mapper.Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        this.setup(context);

        try {
            while(context.nextKeyValue()) {
                this.map(context.getCurrentKey(), context.getCurrentValue(), context);
            }
        } finally {
            this.cleanup(context);
        }

    }

    public class Context extends MapContext<KEYIN, VALUEIN, KEYOUT, VALUEOUT> {
        public Context(Configuration var1, TaskAttemptID conf, RecordReader<KEYIN, VALUEIN> taskid, RecordWriter<KEYOUT, VALUEOUT> reader, OutputCommitter writer, StatusReporter committer, InputSplit reporter) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            super(conf, taskid, reader, writer, committer, reporter, split);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;

public class ExampleMapper<T, X, Y, Z> extends Mapper<T, X, Y, Z> {
    static {
        System.setProperty("job.examplemapper", "true");
    }
}
```

Then extend it, in your program

```
public class MyExampleMapper 
     extends ExampleMapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable>{

   private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
   private Text word = new Text();

   public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
     StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());

     String result = System.getProperty("job.examplemapper")

     if (result.equals("true")) {
       while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
         word.set(itr.nextToken());
         context.write(word, one);
       }
     }
   }
 }
```